# why asp.net mvc does not include the image uploaded folder in the project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

what I have found that the images uploaded by my application are not included in the project and that I have to include them manually image by image so what is the correct way of asp.net mvc project to let the images uploaded to be included in the project.

The following code is the one that upload the images to the folder and creates a unique name for each image. but still those images are not included in the project explorer.

```
public ActionResult Create(Job job, HttpPostedFileBase JobImage)
{
    var value = "999999999";
    var result4 = from app in db.Job where app.UniqueJobImageName.Contains(value) select app;
    if(result4.FirstOrDefault() != null)
    {
        value = generateRandom();
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid && CheckFileType(JobImage.FileName))
    {
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(JobImage.FileName);
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(JobImage.FileName);
        job.JobImage = JobImage.FileName;
        job.UniqueJobImageName = value + ext;
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), value +  ext);
        JobImage.SaveAs(path);
        job.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        job.jobUrl = "";
        job.Month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
        job.DateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
        AllJobModel all = new AllJobModel
        {
            JobTitle = job.JobTitle,
            JobDescription = job.JobDescription,
            JobImage = job.JobImage,
            UniqueJobImageName = job.UniqueJobImageName,
            locationName = job.locationName,
            minimumSalary = job.minimumSalary.ToString(),
            maximumSalary = job.maximumSalary.ToString(),
            jobUrl = job.jobUrl,
            PostedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
            UserId= User.Identity.GetUserId(),
        };

        db.AllJobModel.Add(all);
        db.SaveChanges();
        db.Job.Add(job);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }else if (!CheckFileType(JobImage.FileName))
    {

    }

    return View(job);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtL2l.png)

Comment: Why do you need to include it to the project? It is just content of your web site, but not of project

Comment: the reason why is that when I change something locally I would like it to have effect on the server when the project is uploaded

Comment: What do you mean by "change something locally"? How uploaded images related to this? How do you use those uploaded images?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make any sense. The uploaded images are content created by the user. They are not a deployable component of the site (or, they shouldn't be anyway). They are user-generated content, not developer resources.

If you are looking to effectively migrate your data (i.e. copy database entries and other user-generated content such as image files) from one environment to another, then that is a separate task for which you can create a separate process and/or automated script. Don't confuse it with the job of uploading a new version of your application code.

---

P.S. Even if what you were asking for was a sensible goal, it's impossible anyway - the executable version of your code is not the same as the code you see in Visual Studio in your project. In a modern ASP.NET application the executable code is in a different folder (even when you're running in debug mode in Visual Studio) and it has no concept or knowledge of the original project it was compiled from, or where to find it, or how to interact with it.